# How to change nickname (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a command that changes a nickname to a specific user (Let it be Example # 1234). This command accepts an argument in which a new nickname must be entered, to which the old nickname must be changed - g!Chnick "ExampleNick". I do not know how to change the nickname to users of the Discord server, I tried it through the Guild class, I tried it through the Member class.
(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not hard! For example you can use:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def chnick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    await member.edit(nick=nick)
    await ctx.send(f'Nickname was changed for {member.mention} ')
```

Don't forget a important thing, bot MUST have a permission for changing nicknames and can't change server owner nickname. Test it on other bots or members of server

My advice for you is reading discord.py documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I read the documentation of discord.py, but did not fully understand

Answer (score 1):

[See documentation there](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) and change nickname via `await member.edit(nick="New Nickname")`. Or show your code.