# How do I change the nickname of a user with a command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a !Nick command for my bot, but I don't know how to change the nickname.
I do not know all of Member's properties so that is making this harder. These are some things I have tried:

```
@client.command()
async def Nick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, nick):
    member.setNickname(nick)
```

```
@client.command()
async def Nick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, nick):
    member.change_nickname(f'{nick}')
```

```
@client.command()
async def Nick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, nick):
    member.change_nickname(member, f'{nick}')
```

Every time it just returns "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'setNickname'"(setNickname is this most recent one ive tried).

Comment: Alright, [here's your Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59341147/15489646)

Comment: thank you, this works just fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change nickname (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340143/how-to-change-nickname-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you need this anymore, but here is an example:

```
@BOT.command(aliases=['nickname', 'changenick'])
async def nick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    await member.edit(nick=nick)
    await ctx.send(f'Your nickname got changed to {member.mention}!')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).