# How to change someone's nickname when a user joins the server || Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to add a Clan Tag in the user's name when someone joins the server but I am confused about how to do it. Your help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you attempted? Looking at the docs can help you...

Comment: This links may help: [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.edit), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340143/how-to-change-nickname-discord-py)

Comment: Just a suggestion - would it not be better to add the user to a discord role when they join? This would allow you to do more with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using cogs,

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.prefix,intents = intents)
# You can find Intents in Bot entries on the discord developer site.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# change someone's nickname when a user joins the server

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    await member.edit(nick="nickname here")
```

Answer (score 0):

The bot can detect when a new member joins the guild with the [`on_member_join()` event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.on_member_join). You can then get the member's nickname with [`Member.nick`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.Member.nick) and you can change the member's nickname with [`Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.Member.edit), passing the `nick=` keyword argument.

```py
CLAN_TAG = "TAG"

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.edit(nick=f"[{CLAN_TAG}]{member.nick}")
```

If the member's original nickname was *Nickname*, their new nickname would be *[TAG]Nickname*.

Comment: It didn't work. The user's nick is just like that. I turned on intents