# Discord.py missing permissions when bot role is above all and has admin privileges

Tags: python, discord.py

```
raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'test' raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Constantly getting this error, even though my bot has administrator permissions, also the role is located at the top of the tree.

[image: Showing the bot's role is located at the top]

[image: Bot has admin permissions]

Evem with all of this, I continuously get the error of missing permissions. My role is located underneath the bot's and also has administrative permissions, so I'm not quite sure why this problem is happening.

```py
@tree.command(name='test', description='testing the bot', guild=guild)
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, user:discord.User, *, nickname:str):
    await interaction.user.edit(nick=nickname)
    await interaction.response.send_message(user.mention, ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: Who's nickname are you trying to change? Yours? Are you the server owner?

Comment: I am the server owner, and i'm trying to change a mentioned user's nickname, sorry should've been more clear I'll edit my message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're using `interaction.user` and not `user`. `interaction.user` is the user that *invoked* the command. As this is likely you, the server owner, it fails as a bot can't edit the [server owner's nickname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340143/how-to-change-nickname-discord-py).

```py
@tree.command(name='test', description='testing the bot', guild=guild)
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.User, *, nickname: str):
    await user.edit(nick=nickname)
    await interaction.response.send_message(user.mention, ephemeral=True)
```

Additionally, it might be worth explicitly adding the "manage nicknames" permission as well.

[image]

Comment: I should've thought about this sooner, but yea you are right, thank you very much for your answer!